# Unable to delete local user using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Delete()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to delete local user account using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal`

I am using VS 2010 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1

Here is my code

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    using (var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "test1"))
    {                        
        if (up != null)
        {
            up.Delete();
        }
    }                       
}
```

When `up.Delete()` is called, I receive the exception with the following message:

> The Active Directory object located at the path
>   WinNT://DOMAIN/MACHINENAME is not a container.

What should I do to make `Delete()` work?

Comment: What is your user store? If you are using ADDS then you are setting the wrong ContextType.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contexttype.aspx

Comment: I think it should be `ContextType.Machine` (SAM store) since it is the local user account

Answer (score 0):

You might try specifying the identityType parameter in the [FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) overload:

```
using (var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "test1"))
```

Comment: this does not make any difference (actually, the same UserPrincipal instance is being returned)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that is working for me :

```
try
{
  PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "pwd");

  /* Retreive a user
   */
  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "user3");
  if (user != null)
    user.Delete();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

---

Edited

So for the local machine (SAM) it's the following, exactly the same as your code but the exception management show an *acces denied* error if the the code is not run in an elevated right administrator prompt. I think your error come from that.

```
try
{
  PrincipalContext computerContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

  /* Retreive a user
   */
  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(computerContext, "utilisateur1");
  if (user != null)
    user.Delete();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Console.ReadLine();

Comment: I'm working with local user account, not the domain user account

Comment: well, for now I see that the error just does not reproduce on your machine. Maybe this is an issue with my machine configuration. I run my code using account that has administrator tights and UAC is turned off. I do not recieve "access denied" error, but the error I have shown in my question.